# Open new tab in Safari settings

Tags: safari, tabs

How can I make Safari open new tabs next to the current like in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

It's a hidden preference. Run this command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari TargetedClicksCreateTabs -bool true
```

You'll have to restart Safari for the preference to take effect.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but this does not seem to be exactly an answer to the question. The preference setting does not open the new tab NEXT to the current tab. It makes Safari open tabs instead of new windows on clicking a kink that would otherwise open a new window but the new tab is created right of the rightmost tab.

As i understand the question (I have had no exposure to Chrome so far) the requirement is to create the tab next to the existing one.

Comment: Safari's standard behavior is to _always_ open a tab all the way to the right; this is the closest solution to the question that you can get with Safari's preferences/behavior.

Answer (score 2):

A Safari plugin called [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) should do the job.

It allows you to open tabs, next to the currently active tab (which is what you want) as well as add some extra functionality to your Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Saft](http://pimpmysafari.com/plugins/saft) can handle this, "classic" Safari can't.